# onConnectionSuspended. How to test? When will this code be run?

Tags: android, google-play-games

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
        sendToast("onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    [...]
}
```

I've read the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html

Based on what I read I did a simple test where I connected two peers in a Quick Game. I disabled the WiFi connection on one of them. I thought that I was going to see a toast for onConnectionSuspended. Is there a way to induce that toast to come up for testing purposes?

Thank You

Comment: Please make sure your code is indented properly. Also, what is `RoomStatusUpdateListener`, `RoomUpdateListener`, etc.? Are these relevant to your question? If not, I suggest you remove them to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`onConnectionSuspended` gets called when your app gets disconnected from the Google Play services package (not necessarily the Internet). The callback gets invoked for instance when you go to **Settings > Apps > Google Play services > Force Stop**. Another example is when you would uninstall Google Play services. You would get `onConnectionSuspended` followed by `onConnectionFailed` after a couple of seconds (because a reconnection attempt would fail).

Also do not call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` from `onConnectionSuspended(...)`. Reconnection is handled automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure about your last statement as in the offical Google quickstart apps they're doing it. [source](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/plus/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java)

Comment: I've noticed, in my experience it's handled automatically though.

Comment: According to the author of the code, at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26147518/252080, reconnection is automatic.