# Catch GoogleApiClient.disconnect() callback

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-signin

I want to catch `onDisconnected` callback but neither `onConnectionSuspended` nor `onConnectionFailed` are called.

```
public class mAct extends Activity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

//i'm using this:

protected void createClient() {
        if (gso == null) {
            gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)// required for App Folder sample
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken("MYKEY.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .build();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
    }
//this function calls `onConnected`
protected void connect() {
     if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
         if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
             mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
         }
     }
    }

//but this is not
protected void disconnect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
//to signout I use this

protected void signoutWorker() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            //some setup and exit
                            disconnect();
                        }
                    });

//this works
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
}

//this not works
@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
}
//this not works too
Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    }

}
```

As I understood this new API prevents to call `onConnectionFailed` when `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect` is called.
Can I use callback at the `disconnect()` function ?  Is this a normal behavoiur?

That is:

```
 protected void disconnect() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    myCallbackhere();//this callback
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of method are not disconnect's callback method.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
}
```

> onConnectionSuspended gets called when your app gets disconnected from
>   the Google Play services package (not necessarily the Internet).
>
> check this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350286/onconnectionsuspended-how-to-test-when-will-this-code-be-run)

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
}
```

> and onConnectionFailed get called when method failed like DriveApi.newDriveContents, somthing else.
>
> it support check error or show errorDialog, or retry  when has resolution
>
> check this [quickstart link](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java)

Unfortunately, disconnect doesn't have callback

but googleDrive sign out method is out of network. so you don't worry about sign out without knowing it

just call your method after disconnect()

> try disconnect(), connect without wifi, data

This [googleTopic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/1RiPC8XYP_U) might will help you