# When does "onConnectionSuspended " on Drive-API get called, and how to deal with it?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

[**Docs**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks#constants) say this:

> public abstract void onConnectionSuspended (int cause)
>
> Called when the client is temporarily in a disconnected state. This
>   can happen if there is a problem with the remote service (e.g. a crash
>   or resource problem causes it to be killed by the system). When
>   called, all requests have been canceled and no outstanding listeners
>   will be executed. GoogleApiClient will automatically attempt to
>   restore the connection. Applications should disable UI components that
>   require the service, and wait for a call to onConnected(Bundle) to
>   re-enable them.

I can't cause it to happen in order to investigate how to deal with it. I tried to disconnect from the Internet, but it's not the callback that gets called (onConnectionFailed gets called instead).

Sure it says I should disable UI components, but for how long does it get handled? Will "onConnected" be called shortly after, and always be called after it?

What if I create an activity that all its purpose is to connect to Google Drive? Should it close itself when it reaches onConnectionSuspended ? Or should it ignore it, as soon it will succeed to connect?

Also, as it is called "onConnectionSuspended", does it mean all other callbacks are quite instantaneous ?

Answer (score 1):

You should've gotten the `*onConnectionSuspended*` callback before `*onConnectionFailed*` was called. A [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350286/onconnectionsuspended-how-to-test-when-will-this-code-be-run) indicates that `onConnectionSuspended` will be triggered when your app was disconnected on Google Play Services. A force stop/kill of the Google Play Service can trigger the callback, and after that - `onConnectionFailed` should be called next.

Comment: So ignoring this is a possible option? After all, a callback to something else should occur anyway...

Comment: We've decided not to use Drive API after all. Sorry. Have +1 for the effort .