# Android LocationServices - how to test onConnectionSuspended callback

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-api-client

I'm using Google Play services location API on Android and I'm trying to figure out how to test the onConnectionSuspended(int cause) callback which is part of [GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks).

I've tried turning off WiFi, GPS, etc but I haven't been able to get this callback to trigger. The device I am testing on does not have a cellular service provider so I figured turning both of those off would work...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350286/onconnectionsuspended-how-to-test-when-will-this-code-be-run) describes how you can simulate/test being disconnected from Google Play Service. What is important is to be disconnected from the play service and not necessarily the Internet - as you seem to have assumed in your  testing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oops I didn't even see that post!Thank you.

Comment: My apologies on the delayed response. Thank you, the link provided worked!