# Google API client not connecting again after onConnectionSuspended(int Cause) called

Tags: android, gps, tracking, google-api-client

I have seen this question on OnConnecctionSuspended() call back. 
[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056148/googleapiclient-onconnectionsuspended-should-i-call-mgoogleapiclient-connect/26147518#comment44446026_26147518)

I have an activity where I'm trying to track the KMs traveled from origin to destination when a user clicks a start button (origin) and then clicks stop button (Destination). The issues is that it works perfectly for some 1.5-2 KMs after which the connection is suspended with cause 1, for which the google doc says 'CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED' - A suspension cause informing that the service has been killed. 
As per the answer provided by [hounshell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156767/hounshell) it will automatically try connecting and we dont have to call googleApiClient.connect() method again. I have logged the actions and it is trying to connect.

> Logs
>   333,211038:05,onConnectionSuspended(int cause)- mGoogleApiClient is Connecting?  = true
>   334,211038:05,onConnectionSuspended(int cause)- mGoogleApiClient is Connected?  = false

But even after 2 mins with my phone out in the open with clear skies etc, its not connecting. I have to restart the activity to get the connection again. Can someone help me please???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and the Google API connection would not succeed. I manually made the `connect()` call and delayed by `1000ms`, and only then did my connections succeed.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      googleApiClient.connect();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Strange but works. We have implemented a complete restart mechanism (app) to get this work. Thanks for this.

Comment: i tried this to reconnect but i am unable to connect every time it i'll call onConnectionSuspended() what can i do for that