# What is the GoogleApiClient Reconnect Policy after a connection gets suspended?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

The vague javadoc of GoogleApiClient tells us that:

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.onConnectionSuspended
```

is going to be :

> Called when the client is temporarily in a disconnected state. This can happen if there is a problem with the remote service (e.g. a crash or resource problem causes it to be killed by the system). When called, all requests have been canceled and no outstanding listeners will be executed. GoogleApiClient will automatically attempt to restore the connection. Applications should disable UI components that require the service, and wait for a call to onConnected(Bundle) to re-enable them.

Unfortunately it doesn't tells us how many times it will retry to "restore" the connection. Is there any timeout, exponential backoff , number of retries ?

If it doesn't succeed  magically restoring the connection does it call:

```
OnConnectionFailedListener.onConnectionFailed
```

and when ?

Comment: As of now there is no documentation regarding the GoogleApiClient Reconnect Policy. I would suggest logging your feature/document [request](https://code.google.com/p/android/). This way the document can be updated and to add feature regarding reconnect policy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I've rolled off the project, and code has changed in the meantime...

If I recall correctly, it tries to reconnect once, assuming that the connection was suspended due to a service crash (the most common cause).  Then I would assume that it'd end up calling either `onConnectionFailed()` or `onConnected()`, but I wouldn't rely on that. I think you can verify this by killing the GMS process while your app is connected, but even if evidence shows that this is the case I still wouldn't rely on it unless it's documented.

I would not expect it to retry more than once if it fails to connect, or to ever stop if it connects and the service crashes again.

If I was building something that used the client and I wanted to be as defensive as possible, I wouldn't trust a suspended connection.  I'd explicitly call `disconnect()` and `connect()` again to re-build the connection.